# retrieve the result of Array.map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a similar code to this structure. It seems as if I don't need the async functions here but like I said it's similar to my own code which is kind of long.

Here is my code:

```
const array = [
  { methods: 'user.js'},
  { methods: 'test.js'},
  { methods: 'hello.js' },
];
async function bigTest() {
  async function details() {
    const arr = [];
    const test = [];
    const files = array.map(async (i) => {
      arr.push({
        name: i,
        item: [
          {
            name: 'test',
          },
        ],
      });
      return test.push(arr);
    });
    return Promise.all(files);
  }
  const result = await details();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
bigTest();
```

The `console.log(arr)` returns for me each time the process of pushing into the array:

```
[ { name: { methods: 'user.js', item: [] }, item: [ [Object] ] } ]

[ { name: { methods: 'user.js', item: [] }, item: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: { methods: 'test.js', item: [] }, item: [ [Object] ] } ]

[ { name: { methods: 'user.js', item: [] }, item: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: { methods: 'test.js', item: [] }, item: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: { methods: 'hello.js', item: [] }, item: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

I want to return the last array with all the pushed element but what I get as a result is `[1,2,3]`

and when I do a console.log on the array test, I get duplicate objects

Comment: Side note: why do you use `async`? There is not async API you are calling upon, so why not drop all that `async`?

Comment: in your `.map` you `return test.push(arr);` - wont this make `files` an array of indexes (ie positive itegers) ?

Comment: i'm working on my code and i need them. instead of asking a question with a whole long code, i did a similar code to mine with simple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to return the last array with all the pushed element but what I get as a result is `[1,2,3]`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

So you need to return the element itself and not the result of `test.push(arr)`. Replace `return test.push(arr)` by:

```
test.push(arr);
return test[test.length-1];
```

Then `console.log` only the last item in `result`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result[result.length-1]));
```

```js
const array = [
  { methods: 'user.js', item: [] },
  { methods: 'test.js', item: [] },
  { methods: 'hello.js', item: [] },
];
async function bigTest() {
  async function details() {
    const arr = [];
    const test = [];
    const files = array.map(async (i) => {
      arr.push({ name: i, item: [{ name: 'test' }] });
      test.push(arr);
      return test[test.length-1];
    });
    return Promise.all(files);
  }
  const result = await details();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result[result.length-1]));
}
bigTest();
```

I assume you are using `arr` and `test` for something else, otherwise, you could simplify your code a bit by getting rid of the intermediate arrays and logging the whole result array:

```js
const array = [
  { methods: 'user.js', item: [] },
  { methods: 'test.js', item: [] },
  { methods: 'hello.js', item: [] },
];
async function bigTest() {
  async function details() {
    return Promise.all(array.map(async (i) =>
      ({ name: i, item: [{ name: 'test' }] })
    ));
  }
  const result = await details();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
bigTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

`return test.push(arr);` does not give you the `arr`, it gives you the new length of `test`. Your `files` will be promises for integers, and your `result` will be an array of integers.

Additionally you create an array `arr` and also an array `test` to which you are repeatly pushing the `arr`. It doesn't seem like you want any nesting, so don't `push` multiple times.

You could instead `return test` or `return arr`, but you really simply shouldn't be `push`ing those values yourself. `map` already creates the new array for you, you just need to return the respective value from the callback:

```
async function bigTest() {
  const filePromises = array.map(async (i) => {
    // I assume you await something here, otherwise the `async` is really unnecessary
    return {
//  ^^^^^^
      name: i,
      item: [
        {
          name: 'test',
        },
      ],
    };
  });
  const files = await Promise.all(filePromises);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
}
```

Comment: once i do so, it returns for me [null,null,null]

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`return test.push(arr);`

is returning the new length of the `test` array, which is 1 then 2 then 3, so the files array ends up containing [1,2,3]

You probably want to replace:

`return Promise.all(files);`

with:

`return Promise.all(files).then(() => arr);`

which will execute the promises then return the contents of the arr array.

Alternatively, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you may be able to simplify to:

```
async function bigTest() {
  async function details() {
    const files = array.map(async (i) => {
      return {
        name: i,
        item: [
          {
            name: 'test',
          },
        ],
      };
    });
    return Promise.all(files);
  }
  const result = await details();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
bigTest();
```